How can I inlet my faces to be closer to the drawn outline?
I have been using the inlet tool but it seems to inlet my face not enough in the vertical. As shown in the picture the new face is barely smaller in the vertical while the horizontal are too small. How can I inlet my face to be closer to the drawn outline in the second picture ? 


Apply the scale to your object in Object mode with Ctrl-A > Scale and then try again. Incidentally, I think you mean "inset" not "inlet"!

Do apply the scale as well but after that you can set the pivot point to individual origins and scale them along an axis or normal of the faces to modify them further

